# Having problems while trying to execute an Acceleo module in standalone mode

Tags: java, eclipse, acceleo

I have successfully created an Acceleo module for M2T purposes and am trying to execute it from a Java program.
This is what I tried :

```
String[] str = {"/home/hamza/workspace/HLRedundancy/model/System1.xmi", "/home/hamza/workspace/HLRedundancy/"};
Generate.main(str);
```

`Generate` being the name of the Acceleo module I created and thus, the name of the Java class containing the Acceleo generation methods.

Here is the error I'm always getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.AcceleoEvaluationException: The type of the first parameter of the main template named 'generateElement' is a proxy.
at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AcceleoService.doGenerate(AcceleoService.java:566)
at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AbstractAcceleoGenerator.generate(AbstractAcceleoGenerator.java:193)
at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AbstractAcceleoGenerator.doGenerate(AbstractAcceleoGenerator.java:158)
at HighLevelGenerator.main.Generate.doGenerate(Generate.java:250)
at HighLevelGenerator.main.Generate.main(Generate.java:160)
at Execute.main(Execute.java:11)
```

I've been searching for a while about this error but I have no idea about its cause.
Any idea about a solution to my problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this issue is failure in properly registering the metamodel and factory corresponding to your inpu model (System1.xmi).

If you look at the comments in the generated class "Generate.java", you will notice a number of places where we indicate steps to follow if running in standalone. The most important begin registerPackages where you are required to register your metamodel.

If you debug the launch down to the point where the model is loaded (place a breakpoint right after the line `model = ModelUtils.load(newModelURI, modelResourceSet);`), you can look at the `model.eResource().getErrors()` list to see whether there were errors loading your model.

You might also be interested in looking at this [video describing the process](http://www.obeonetwork.com/page/acceleo-stand-alone-launch) (registration required) .

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I added the following piece of code :
`if (!isInWorkspace(HLRedundancyModelPackage.class)) {          resourceSet.getPackageRegistry().put(HLRedundancyModelPackage.eINSTANCE.getNsURI(), HLRedundancyModelPackage.eINSTANCE);
}`


to the method `registerPackages` so I guess my metamodel is registered. Since I'm using `.xmi` files, I did not register any factory.

However, I'm still getting the same error !

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample with which we could reproduce this? (easisest would be through the Eclipse forum at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/24/ ). Without debugging a little (see my answer for a pointer to "where" to debug), this kind of issue is a little hard to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the first line of your acceleo module,
what is the URI of the metamodel? Does it start with 'http://' ?

Maybe this can help:
[Acceleo stand alone - first parameter is proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957861/acceleo-stand-alone-first-parameter-is-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

This issue happen when your meta model contains sub-packages and the top package not contain any class.
to  solve the problem, add a Dummy class the the top package and regenerate the meta-model code. It worked fine for me.