# Acceleo stand alone - first parameter is proxy

Tags: eclipse-emf, acceleo

It may seem like I am asking a question already asked before, but the solutions indicated in the other forum posts don't work for me.

I am trying to run an Acceleo project in a standalone.

```java
public void registerPackages(ResourceSet resourceSet) {
    super.registerPackages(resourceSet);

    if(!isInWorkspace(PSMAndroid.PSMAndroidPackage.class)){
        System.out.println("uri: "+PSMAndroid.PSMAndroidPackage.eNS_URI); 
            resourceSet.getPackageRegistry().put(PSMAndroid.PSMAndroidPackage.eNS_URI, PSMAndroid.PSMAndroidPackage.eINSTANCE);
    }
}
```

And also:

```java
public void registerResourceFactories(ResourceSet resourceSet) {
    super.registerResourceFactories(resourceSet);
    resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("psmandroid",new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
```

}

The module looks like this:

```java
[module componentModule('org.colpaert.mathias.PSMAndroid')]
```

I am getting following error:

> org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.AcceleoEvaluationException: The type of the first parameter of the main template named 'generateModel' is a proxy.

I looked at other posts, but none of that works for me. ([here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/225929/) and [here](http://dentrassi.de/2011/08/11/struggling-with-acceleo-3-0-after-eclipse-3-7-upgrade/))

The generator worked when launched as "acceleo application", without the lines of code above. When I add the lines, running as java application I get the error above. But when I try to run as "acceleo application" again, I get following error:

[image: error]

So that does not work anymore.

What should I do?

extra info: I added the ecore model (project with model & genmodel etc) as a project reference in the build path properties of my acceleo generation project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in my metamodel URI. The metamodel was defined using ecore, 
you should always put "http://" in front of the metamodel URI!

The name of my metamodel was: 
org.colpaert.mathias.PSMAndroid, it is was imported in my acceleo module as following:

> [module model('org.colpaert.mathias.PSMAndroid')/]

This caused acceleo to look for the metamodel in a path relative to the module file. In a standalone, after compilation, this is just the /bin folder.

I changed my ecore metamodel URI, regenerated the genmodel (etc). Next I changed the acceleo module to:

> [module model('http://org.colpaert.mathias.PSMAndroid')/],

Cleaned the solution, recompiled and it worked.

Big thanks to Stéphane Bégaudeau, he solved this [here](http://www.obeonetwork.com/group/acceleo-fr/forum/topics/stand-alone-type-of-parameter-is-proxy?commentId=6359481%3aComment:40975&xg_source=msg_com_gr_forum) (its in french)